# how to grant privileges table to user account?

Tags: oracle, cmd, oracle11g

so I want to grant an update to a user account like this

```
grant update on stuff to admin1;
```

but after I select * from admin1.stuff, an error "table or view does not exist". how can I see the data table in the user account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presume you're currently connected as user `nanatua` and ran

```
grant update on stuff to admin1;
```

It lets user `admin1` to **update** values in table `stuff` you own. Nothing else.

If you want to let it **query** (select) data from that table, you have to grant it:

```
grant select on stuff to admin1;
```

Then connect as `admin1` and run

```
select * from nanatua.stuff;
```

Not vice versa! as you tried to; command you used (`select * from admin1.stuff`) means that user `admin1` owns the table, but it is not.

Comment: oh ok i get it now. thank you